# How can I extract objects several layers deep using the map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a trying to access the change order information as seen below to create a list of all the change_order_names. Using the current code I am getting the results I have posted. Will someone show me how I can access the change order information and produce the list?

```
if (componentType == CHANGE_ORDER_TYPE) {
        if (!this.props.data) {
            return null;
        } else {
            const changeList = this.props.data.map(function (result) {
                return (result.change_orders);
            });
            // return resultsList;
            console.log(changeList);
        }
    }
```

This is the current response from the map method above.

```
[  
 [  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "change_order_name":"change 1",
     "project_id":"1",
     "cws_change_order_id":"33214324",
     "slug":"change-1",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  },
  {  
     "id":2,
     "change_order_name":"change 2",
     "project_id":"1",
     "cws_change_order_id":"3211324",
     "slug":"change-2",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  }
],
[  
  {  
     "id":3,
     "change_order_name":"change 3",
     "project_id":"2",
     "cws_change_order_id":"3234324",
     "slug":"change-3",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  },
  {  
     "id":4,
     "change_order_name":"change 4",
     "project_id":"2",
     "cws_change_order_id":"6234532",
     "slug":"change-4",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  }
],
[  
  {  
     "id":5,
     "change_order_name":"change 5",
     "project_id":"3",
     "cws_change_order_id":"3124214",
     "slug":"change-5",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  }
]
]
```

[image]

Comment: What's the desired result? Please be clear about what you're trying to achieve and in exactly what way your current code is failing; consider reviewing [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, I will edit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I dug down to get get access to the individual change_orders

```
if (componentType == CHANGE_ORDER_TYPE) {
        if (!this.props.data) {
            return null;
        } else {
            const changeList = this.props.data.map(function (result) {
                return (result.change_orders);
            });
            let changeOrdersArr = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < changeList.length; i++) {
                let inner = changeList[i];
                for (let z = 0; z < inner.length; z++) {
                    changeOrdersArr.push(inner[z])
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your desired output is, but I think you want a single array with all change_orders in it?  If this is correct then you can use the reduce function after your current map function:

```
if (componentType == CHANGE_ORDER_TYPE) {
    if (!this.props.data) {
        return null;
    } else {
        const changeList = this.props.data.map(function (result) {
            return (result.change_orders);
        }).reduce((output, item) => [...output, ...item], []);
        // return changeList;
        console.log(changeList);
    }
}
```

```js
const mapOutput = [  
 [  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "change_order_name":"change 1",
     "project_id":"1",
     "cws_change_order_id":"33214324",
     "slug":"change-1",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  },
  {  
     "id":2,
     "change_order_name":"change 2",
     "project_id":"1",
     "cws_change_order_id":"3211324",
     "slug":"change-2",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  }
],
[  
  {  
     "id":3,
     "change_order_name":"change 3",
     "project_id":"2",
     "cws_change_order_id":"3234324",
     "slug":"change-3",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  },
  {  
     "id":4,
     "change_order_name":"change 4",
     "project_id":"2",
     "cws_change_order_id":"6234532",
     "slug":"change-4",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  }
],
[  
  {  
     "id":5,
     "change_order_name":"change 5",
     "project_id":"3",
     "cws_change_order_id":"3124214",
     "slug":"change-5",
     "created_at":null,
     "updated_at":null
  }
]
];

const change_orders = mapOutput.reduce((orders, arr) => [...orders,...arr],[]);

console.log(change_orders);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I haven't used reduce before. This is what I was looking for.